# gg in sourced file goes to line 2 in vim

Tags: csv, vim, vi

I'm experimenting with running a sequence of commands on a csv file; doing some replacements, changing some stuff. I open the file in vim and use `so! filewithcommands`. But `gg` will never go to the top of the file, always to the second position.

contents of samplefile.csv:

```
sometext;morechars
nextline;withsomemoredata
areyou;gettingthepoint
```

contents of filewithcommands:

```
gg
```

When I open `vim --clean` and run `:so! filewithcommands` the cursor will jump to the **second** line for some reason. I've tried `:0` but the same thing happens. Running Ubuntu with Vim v 9.0.2121.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands in your `filewithcommands` are supposed to be Ex commands so `gg`, a normal mode command, has nothing to do there. Actually, that is what Vim is trying to tell you with:

```
Error detected while processing /path/to/filewithcommands:
line    1:
E492: Not an editor command: gg
```

More information is provided by `:help 492`:

```
  Not an editor command ~

You tried to execute a command that is neither an Ex command nor
a user-defined command.
```

Error messages are a good thing and skipping them is never a good idea. Case in point: `gg` is wrong and won't do what you expect no matter what. Adding a `!` to skip the error message won't make `gg` magically do what it can't do. All it will do is deprive *you* of an opportunity to understand the problem and fix it.

The Ex command for moving the cursor to the top of the buffer is:

```
:1
```

so that is what you should put in your `filewithcommands`:

```
1
```

(the `:` is not necessary in that context)

[image: ex]

Alternatively, you can use `:help :normal` to execute normal mode commands in an Ex context. Using the following in your `filewithcommands` will have the same effect as `1`:

```
normal! gg
```

Comment: Thank you! I was indeed under the impression it were all normal commands.

Comment: `:help :source` literally says "Read Ex commands from {file}.  These are commands that start with a ":"."